# how to test data from http service returning multiple observables

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-test

I have a data service which fetches the data from server and makes multiple requests which then return an array of observables. I want to test the data.

What i tried doing is in the mockrespone I sent array which contains two observables i dont know if thats the right way to test data.

But tests are failing especially the last three tests in the async test block

```
   beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        DataService,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
          useFactory:
          (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
            return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
          }
        }
      ],
      imports: [
        HttpModule
      ]
    });
    mockBackend = getTestBed().get(MockBackend);
  }));
```

Comment: Your service does not return an array of Observables at all. Just look at its return type: `Observable<any>`. It' returns **one** observable: `return Observable.forkJoin(Observables)`. Subscribing to this objervable, on the other hand, is supposed to send 2, 4 or 6 http requests, depending on the state of the service. My first advice would be to use HttpClient instead of the deprecated Http service. It's much better designed, and much easier to test.

Comment: Jb, the problem is that i have made my project based on http service. And today is the last submission date, It will decide whether ill get the job or not. Please help. Please help me with this code. to use http client it will take time for me to learn it and successfully implement it. If you could help me with this id be grateful to you for the rest of my life

Comment: You only focused on the last part. Now read the first part again.

Comment: so how am i suppose to test it. sorry i am a noob. And should i test if the service returns an observable or should i test for the data being returned.

Comment: You should test that, when setting charId to falsy and comicsId to falsy, calling tthe method, subscribing to the observable it returns, after you've mocked http, you get back an array containing the two expected responses. Same with the 4 expected response if charId is truthy. Same for the 6 expected responses when comicsId is truthy. Note that a well-designed service should generally not observables of http responses, but observables of responses, i.e. it should use the map operator to extract the data.

Comment: jb? this is the last part of my project that i am stuck at. This will do a great deal to me. It will get me the job ive been working hard for so long. Please help.

Comment: thanks for your answer jb and taking out from your time

Comment: Just one last request. can you please write the code as answer. please thats all. But thanks for all the help so far. thank you

Comment: Do I get the job, then?

Comment: lol, you are founder of ninja squad. Btw i read that book ninja sqaud v 1.8

Comment: I know you are a super busy man. i shouldnt have asked this to you

Comment: but you are the only one who responded to my question. so you are my only hope

Comment: this would solve my problem. but that be asking to much of you. i understand. if you could

Comment: ok I offer you Technical Co-founder of next stackoverflow id be launching soon

Comment: Please, stop begging. It's your job to write this code, I told you where you were wrong, and what you were supposed to do. Stop wasting time begging. Instead, try to understand your code, and try something. The world won't collapse if you haven't managed to write this test. And, as an interviewer, I'd much prefer see you be honest, explain whatyou're supposed to do and see you understand the principle, rather than show me code that you've not written and that you don't understand.

Comment: thats so dissrespectful jb. just wanted the answer, this what this site all about. but fine.

Comment: If we can't be civil to each other then we are using this website wrong

Comment: May I also suggest you use HttpClient instead of Http, which is deprecated, I think that will make your testing go easier